# Google Shopping atom feed and actual google shopping website data

Tags: google-shopping-api

i am using google shopping api to get the sellers data as an atom feed but sometimes the google atom feed have less shops that the actual number of shops that i can see on the google shopping website when using the same search keyword or ean code.

what might cause this, are the there options for shops to make their product data hidden in the atom feed?!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** As paging is not the issue, the OP is correct in stating that there is a way for merchants to exclude their results from API requests. On the [Product Feed Specification](http://support.google.com/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188494#other), there is an `excluded_destination` parameter which can be configured for a [particular destination](http://support.google.com/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=191180).

---

You are likely running into a `paging` situation. Google (and other) APIs will usually not return all of the results for a particular query in the response (think if you were to query something that returned 10,000,000 results - that could be a lot for your program to handle as well as burdensome for the provider to provide).

In order to circumvent this, many APIs provide a parameter that lets you go to the 'next page' of results. The Shopping API provides just such a parameter (`nextLink`), which you can append to your query to get the page of results following the current one

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/v1/reference-response-format):

```
{
  "kind": "shopping#products",
  "etag": value,
  "id": "tag:google.com,2010:shopping/products",

  "selfLink": value,
  "nextLink": value,
  "previousLink": value,

  "totalItems": value,
  "startIndex": value,
  "itemsPerPage": value,
  "currentItemCount": value,

  content module,
  ...
  content module,

  "items": [
    product resource
  ]
}
```

Where `nextLink` = `Link to the next page of products, omitted if there is no next page`

Comment: paging is not the problem, i wish it was, its more about for eaxmple the website shows 3 shops for a product and in the atom feed i get 2

Comment: @user1570048 Ah gotcha (sorry, probably should have assumed you'd know that :) ). As for the reason, I think you are actually correct - it looks like there is an option to specifically exclude products from the API (see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-search-api-for-shopping/cV3mqk5kTtU/lxrDPdoPAnEJ). I will do a little more digging into how exactly you do this and update the answer for posterity's sake :)

Comment: @user1570048 Updated the answer, which is basically just confirming your suspicions :)